# Implementing Azure Key Vault with .Net Core 3.0 & IHostBuilder

Tags: azure-keyvault, .net-core-3.0

I'm having trouble figuring out how to configure my application to use Key Vault in my Program.cs file with .NET Core 3.0 Preview. All examples I've found are with Web Host Builder, but that has been replaced with a Generic Host Builder in 3.0.

Here is the example code I've found using Web Host Builder:

```
public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
   WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
      .ConfigureAppConfiguration((ctx, builder) =>
      {
            var azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
            var keyVaultClient = new KeyVaultClient(
               new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(
                  azureServiceTokenProvider.KeyVaultTokenCallback));
               builder.AddAzureKeyVault(
                  "myendpoint", keyVaultClient, new DefaultKeyVaultSecretManager());
         }
   ).UseStartup<Startup>()
   .Build();
```

And here is what I have so far:

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                    var azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
                    var keyVaultClient = new KeyVaultClient(
                        new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(
                            azureServiceTokenProvider.KeyVaultTokenCallback));
                });
```

It's this line that I cannot figure out how to implement correctly:

```
builder.AddAzureKeyVault("myendpoint", keyVaultClient, new DefaultKeyVaultSecretManager());
```

Any helps/tips/advice/anything at all would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it working with the following code!!

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();

                }).ConfigureAppConfiguration((ctx, builder) =>
                {
                    var azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
                    var keyVaultClient = new KeyVaultClient(
                    new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(
                    azureServiceTokenProvider.KeyVaultTokenCallback));
                    builder.AddAzureKeyVault("myendpoint", keyVaultClient, new DefaultKeyVaultSecretManager());
                });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The .net core 3.0 is in preview which is not stable and Perfect function.

[.NET Core](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Core) 3 was announced on May 7, 2019, at Microsoft Build. Currently preview builds are available. An official release is planned for September 2019. You could wait for Release version or give your feedback.

Comment: It's not release, but Key Vault can still be implemented with .NET Core Preview.